# Building textlive source in BLFS

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-from-scratch

I am trying to build texlive source in BLFS (Beyond Linux From Scratch).

```
export TEXARCH=$(uname -m | sed -e s/i.86/i386/ -e s/$/-linux/) &&
mkdir texlive-build &&
cd texlive-build    &&

../configure                                        \
--prefix=/opt/texlive/2015                      \
--bindir=/opt/texlive/2015/bin/$TEXARCH         \
--datarootdir=/opt/texlive/2015                 \
--includedir=/opt/texlive/2015/include          \
--infodir=/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/info \
--libdir=/opt/texlive/2015/lib                  \
--mandir=/opt/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/doc/man   \
--disable-native-texlive-build                  \
--disable-static --enable-shared                \
--with-system-cairo                             \
--with-system-fontconfig                        \
--with-system-freetype2                         \
--with-system-gmp                               \
--with-system-graphite2                         \
--with-system-harfbuzz                          \
--with-system-icu                               \
--with-system-libgs                             \
--with-system-libpaper                          \
--with-system-libpng                            \
--with-system-mpfr                              \
--with-system-pixman                            \
--with-system-poppler                           \
--with-system-xpdf                              \
--with-system-zlib                              \
--with-banner-add= - BLFS &&

make
```

I am getting following errors even though I have installed all the packages.

checking requested system libpaper library... failed
checking requested system libpng library... failed
checking requested system freetype2 library... failed
checking requested system pixman library... failed
checking requested system cairo library... failed
checking requested system gmp library... failed
checking requested system mpfr library... failed
checking requested system poppler library... failed
checking requested system xpdf library... failed
checking requested system graphite2 library... failed
checking requested system icu library... failed
checking requested system harfbuzz library... failed
configure: error: some requested system libraries failed

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: Or you can delete it here and _then_ post it on Unix & Linux SE. Saves moderator time that way :)

Answer (score 1):

As the book mentions there is  circular dependency problem, between `freetype`, `harfbuzz` and `graphite2`.

[image: circular_deps_problem_harfbuzz_graphite2_freetype]

So first build (as the book describes)

- `harfbuzz`

Then build the other two libraries

- `freetype`
- `graphite2`

Now that you have the three, rebuild the first(harfbuzz) but ensure you add the `--with-graphite2=yes` flag to the `configure` line, `freetype` will be autodetected but graphite2 won't, so add the flag

- `harfbuzz` **(--with-graphite2=yes)**

Finally rebuild the other two libraries just to be sure

- `freetype`
- `graphite2`

And then go back to compiling `texlive`.